# Xgboost. obtain the booster from the best iteration

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I am using Xgboost.train to train my model; however, i am not sure how to obtain the booster from the best iteration instead of the booster from the last iteration.

```
    xgb1=xgb.train(self.params,xgtrain,num_boost_round=self.num_boost_round,early_stopping_rounds=self.early_stopping_rounds,evals=watchlist)
    print xgb1.best_score
    print xgb1.best_iteration
    print xgb1.best_ntree_limit
```

Answer (score 3):

You can setup this when do prediction in the model as:

```
preds = xgb1.predict(testset, ntree_limit=xgb1.best_iteration)
```

Or by using the param `early_stopping_rounds` that guarantee that you'll get the tree nearby the best tree. But be careful with this param, cause the evaluation value can be in a local minimum or maximum (depending of the evaluation function).

You can see here too: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/264

Answer (score 3):

`ntree_limit` is deprecated, you can use `iteration_range`, by default xgboost uses all the trees for prediction, if `iteration_range` is specified the trees in the range will be used for prediciton, you can combine this with a learning curve to get the same result as `early_stopping_rounds`, so if you see your validation set performance stagnate after `n` rounds you can use that in the `iteration_range` to get predictions from the booster model till `n`

```
preds = xgb1.predict(testset, iteration_range = (0, n))
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, if you use early_stopping_rounds, you can use xgb1.best_iteration  and thus iteration_range = (0, xgb1.best_iteration+1)